# Logistic regression with BY statement ERROR message

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm currently working on a SAS program that processes 50 logistic regression for 50 different samples. I previously had help on this thread ([How to loop a logistic regression n number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976788/how-to-loop-a-logistic-regression-n-number-of-times/49986534#49986534)), people advised me to use a BY statement to avoid looping this process n times. Works really well but I get this ERROR MESSAGE:

*ERROR: No valid observations due either to missing values in the response, explanatory, frequency, or weight variable, or to 
       nonpositive frequency or weight values.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      Sample Replicate Number=.*

You'll find my code below, if any of you have an idea of where does it come from, I'm open to anything, thank you in advance!

```
proc surveyselect data=TOP_1 NOPRINT out=ALEA_1
    seed=0
    method=urs 
    outhits 
    reps=5
    n=300;
run; 

proc surveyselect data=TOP_0 NOPRINT out=ALEA_0
    seed=0
    method=urs 
    outhits 
    reps=5
    n=300;
run; 


PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE APPEND_TABLE As
    SELECT * FROM ALEA_1
      OUTER UNION CORR
    SELECT * FROM ALEA_0;
QUIT;


/* Régression logistique*/
DATA WORK.TMP0TempTableAddtnlPredictData;
    SET WORK.APPEND_TABLE(IN=__ORIG) WORK.BASE_PREDICT_2;
    __FLAG=__ORIG;
    __DEP=TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017;
    if not __FLAG then TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017=.;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE VIEW WORK.SORTTempTableSorted AS
        SELECT *
    FROM WORK.TMP0TempTableAddtnlPredictData
        ORDER BY REPLICATE;
QUIT;
TITLE;
TITLE1 "Résultats de la régression logistique";
FOOTNOTE;
FOOTNOTE1 "Généré par le Système SAS (&_SASSERVERNAME, &SYSSCPL) le %TRIM(%QSYSFUNC(DATE(), NLDATE20.)) à %TRIM(%SYSFUNC(TIME(), TIMEAMPM12.))";
PROC LOGISTIC DATA=WORK.SORTTempTableSorted
        PLOTS(ONLY)=ROC
    ;
    By Replicate;
    CLASS age_classe    (PARAM=EFFECT) Flag_bq_principale   (PARAM=EFFECT) flag_univers_detenus     (PARAM=EFFECT) csp_1    (PARAM=EFFECT) SGMT_FIDELITE    (PARAM=EFFECT) situ_fam_1   (PARAM=EFFECT);
    MODEL TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017 (Event = '1') [...6## Heading ##] /
        SELECTION=STEPWISE
        SLE=0.1
        SLS=0.1
        INCLUDE=0
        LINK=LOGIT
    ;

    OUTPUT OUT=WORK.PREDLogRegPredictions(LABEL="Statistiques et prédictions de régression logistique pour WORK.APPEND_TABLE" WHERE=(NOT ws__FLAG))
        PREDPROBS=INDIVIDUAL;
RUN;
QUIT;

DATA WORK.PREDLogRegPredictions; 
    set WORK.PREDLogRegPredictions; 
    TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017=__DEP; 
    _FROM_=__DEP;
    DROP __DEP; 
    DROP __FLAG;
RUN ;
QUIT ;


/* Création du fichier de sorti final*/
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE MODELE_RESULTS As
    SELECT IDCLI_CALCULE, IP_1
    FROM PREDLogRegPredictions;
RUN;
QUIT;

ODS GRAPHICS OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably from this:

```
DATA WORK.TMP0TempTableAddtnlPredictData;
    SET WORK.APPEND_TABLE(IN=__ORIG) WORK.BASE_PREDICT_2;
    __FLAG=__ORIG;
    __DEP=TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017;
    if not __FLAG then TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017=.;
RUN;
```

You're appending a dataset that does not have a replicate number on it here.  I'm not really sure I follow what this dataset is - are you intending this to be added to *each* replicate perhaps?  Then you might do something like this (untested):

```
DATA WORK.TMP0TempTableAddtnlPredictData;
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (eof);
     SET WORK.APPEND_TABLE(IN=__ORIG) end=eof;
     output;
    end;

    do replicate = 1 to 5;
     do n_predict = 1 to nobs_predict;
      set WORK.BASE_PREDICT_2 nobs=nobs_predict point=n_predict;
      __FLAG=__ORIG;
      __DEP=TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017;
      if not __FLAG then TOP_CREDIT_HABITAT_2017=.;
      output;
     end;
    end;
  stop;
RUN;
```

This is the complicated way to get 5 copies of that, one for each replicate.  But I'm not sure that's actually what you want - does it even have all of the variables you need?  Are you sure you didn't mean to MERGE instead of SET?

Separately, I don't understand why you use the SQL step to append the two samples.  I'd either do that in the same data step here or I'd use `PROC APPEND`, both would be faster than the SQL union and then immediately appending more to the dataset.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your answer. Actually it seems to keep all variables but I get a ROC value higher than 0.99 which is good but really unexpected (should be around 0.8/0.9). But it seems that you're right, merging should be a better way than SET for this example. Does it mean I simply need to replace SET by MERGE? I'm relatively new in SQL...
PROC APPEND is way more efficient apparently, didn't think about this, thank you again

Comment: `SET` or `MERGE` just depends on what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to add more observations? Or are you trying to add more variables to the observations you have now.